# Powershell - Calling child functions from variables

Tags: function, powershell, variables

How do I call a sub-set of functions within PowerShell? I've tried playing with switches but it would need a switch passed in.

How can I achieve this with a set of true or false flags from within the script?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You can assign a *Boolean* value to a variable and test against that: `$HotToday = $true; if ($HotToday -eq $true) {...`.

Comment: I thought about doing this, but I'd have a list of if statements, for instance if I have 2 set to true and 2 to false, how would my if statement handle this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Writing a build script framework or something like that?

Comment: Without providing the __code__ you already have / what you have tried is hard for people to tell what is the best practice / best approach you should take with your __code__. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68293682/edit) your question and with a minimal code example in order for us to help you.

Comment: Ha! Mathias my hero, exactly that, a list of booleans that basically show $true or $false at the top of the script, for each true call a sub function, for each false do nothing. I just don't know how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to think about this as "calling into" (or executing "within") a script that contains a set of function definitions - flip your mental model around and think about the script with your function definitions as something to *import* into the script that makes the calls.

Let's say you've written 3 utility functions to do *something* - now place them all in a single file called `functions.ps1`:

```
# functions.ps1

function taskX {
  # ...
}

function taskY {
  # ...
}

function taskZ {
  # ...
}
```

Now that we have a "toolbox" with the functions we might need, we can open it up and load the functions into any other script (or the prompt if you're using PowerShell interactively), by [*dot sourcing* the script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts):

```
. .\functions.ps1
```

This will make PowerShell execute the script *in the calling scope* - that basically means that things like functions that were defined and variables that were assigned in the script will still persist in the current environment after the script is done executing - meaning that we can now call `taskX` or `taskY`.

So now, your script do actually *do stuff* (let's call it the *driver*) will look like this:

```
# driver.ps1
# import functions
. $PSScriptRoot\functions.ps1

# call functions with the desired parameter arguments
taskX -SomeSwitch
taskY
```

The `$PSScriptRoot` variable resolves to the directory of the currently executing script, so make sure `driver.ps1` is in the same directory as `functions.ps1`.